# ServerInfo DiscordJS Issue

Tags: discord.js

My issue here is when I execute the command the owner is only undefined instead of the actual owner of the server. How can I fix this issue?

```
module.exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {
    const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');

    message.delete();
    const guild = message.guild;
    const Emojis = guild.emojis.cache.size || "No Emoji!";
    const Roles = guild.roles.cache.size || "No Roles!";
    const Members = guild.memberCount;
    const Humans = guild.members.cache.filter(member => !member.user.bot).size;
    const Bots = guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.user.bot).size;
    const owner = guild.owner.user.tag 

    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle(guild.name + " Information!")
      .setColor("2F3136")
      .setThumbnail(guild.iconURL())
      .addField(`Name`, `${guild.name}`, true)
      .addField(`Owner`, `${owner}`, true)
      .addField(`ID`, `${guild.id}`, true)
      .addField(`Roles Count`, `${Roles}`, true)
      .addField(`Emojis Count`, `${Emojis}`, true)
      .addField(`Members Count`, `${Members}`, true)
      .addField(`Humans Count`, `${Humans}`, true)
      .addField(`Bots Count`, `${Bots}`, true)
      .addField(`Server Created At`, guild.createdAt.toDateString())
      .setFooter(`Requested by ${message.author.username}`)
      .setTimestamp();

    message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });
}

module.exports.config = {
    name: "serverinfo",
    aliases: [""]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that there isn't an `owner` property in a [`Guild`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild). To get the owner you have two methods:

Method 1 is using the [`.fetchOwner()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=fetchOwner) method of a [`Guild`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild)

```js
const owner = await message.guild.fetchOwner().user.tag
```

Method 2 is getting the owner id and then fetching the user from `guild.members`:

```js
const owner = message.guild.members.cache.get(message.guild.ownerId)
```

You can choose which method is better for you

Comment: Thank you. I used method 2 and it worked.